# ASP.NET MVC Sub Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a ASP.NET MVC application at a root level (e.g. http://example.com), and have now deployed an additional ASP.NET MVC application as a sub-application (e.g. http://example.com/api). I have set the sub-application as an "Application" in IIS.

However, whenever I try to navigate to the sub-application, I am getting a 403.14 Forbidden error. It's like the sub-application isn't getting picked up as an ASP.NET MVC application. If I try and hit a url which has a controller/action method in the sub-application (e.g. http://example.com/api/home/index"), I get a 404 response.

In terms of setup, the only differences I can see in IIS Manager is a lack of an "ISAPI Filters" icon for the sub-application. I am running .NET 4.5, ASP.NET MVC 4, and IIS 7.5.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this ASP.NET MVC sub-application working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the following config from the `<system.webServer>` config in my child application:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

After I put that in, it started recognising the child application as an ASP.NET MVC site.